# Rest API delayed response slowing down system

Tags: api, rest

may be this is a dump question but please bear with me and help understand the concept.

There are two servers interacting using REST APIs, there is a default timeout of 2 minutes.

System A is trying to call System B using REST API and System B is in fault state due to database issue- means getting requests but not responding but System A keep sending hundreds of requests and eventually complaining of slowness.

My understanding is - System A - reserves/consumes some resource while making each request which is waiting at least 2 min until timeout on System B - so if hundreds of requests queued then will slow system down.

I have .net core app running on IIS. Please suggest if this understanding is correct or can be other factors? When System B came back to normal state both system behave correctly.

Comment: Yes this sounds reasonable. I would consider it a bug if one of your systems is down, and another system continuously hits it with more requests.

Comment: Agree it is a design issue as well that tight coupling causing other system cause slowness. System should return some error code - what is recommendation in this case?

Comment: You can do things with request pools and queues, but at high scalability switching from a request/response model to an event system is sometimes desirable. It's hard to give a specific recommendation with confidence though.

Comment: Agree - we are working to move towards event based system. Thank you for sparing time to review it and provide comments. Appreciate it. Once more quick Question if you have moment - How we identify resource consumption when a REST request is created by System A to B ? to get idea how much it will be eating when let say 100 request on queue and rest waiting?

Comment: Don't guess, measure.